# Network unreachable in android

Tags: android, sockets, networking, udp

I am trying to make an android application which would open a datagram socket and broadcast data via it. It works fine when my phones are connected to a wifi network which is created by my router.

Now, if I create a wifi network by setting "Mobile hotspot" in one of the android phones, the application on the android phone in which hotspot is started received the data from other phones but when i try to send the data,it said network unreachable...I am totally help less in this...can anybody help me in this??

Comment: I am facing a same problem but occasionally. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. Did someone find a solution?